# Graph/binary tree coding problem - find number of people who can pay for dinner (connected components?)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am working on a coding problem and my solution passes around 1/4 of the test cases and I can't figure out why.

The code challenge is:

> There are *n* people in a company, numbered from 1 to *n*, and every person (except for one) has a boss.
>
> At a dinner, a subset *m* from the *n* people from the company come. You want to figure out how many people could pay for the dinner. A person can only pay for the dinner if their boss (or indirectly any boss above them, so for example their bosses boss) is not present at the dinner.
>
> #### Input
>
> **First line**: *n* and *m* separated by space
>
> **Second line**: *n* integers, integer *i* denoting that the *i*<sup>th</sup> person's boss is person *i*. If *i* is 0, the person doesn't have a boss (he is the main boss)
>
> **Third line:** *m* integers, denoting the people that come to the dinner
>
> #### Output
>
> The number of people who could pay for the dinner
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> 6 5
> 5 4 4 5 0 1
> 5 1 3 2 4
> ```
>
> ### Answer
>
> ```
> 1
> ```
>
> The main boss is present, he is the only one that can pay.

I was thinking of making the boss relations into a graph and then counting the number of distinct components. Is this a correct approach? Do I maybe have 0-index errors?

My code:

```
class Graph:
     
    def __init__(self, V, ppl):
 
        self.V = V
        self.ppl = ppl
        self.M = len(ppl)
 
        self.adj = [[] for i in range(self.V)]
        self.visited = [False for i in range(self.V)]
 
    def NumberOfconnectedComponents(self):
         
        visited = [False for i in range(self.V)]
         
        count = 0
         
        for v in range(self.M):
            if (self.visited[self.ppl[v]] == False):
                self.DFSUtil(v)
                count += 1
                 
        return count
         
    def DFSUtil(self, v):
 
        self.visited[v] = True
 
        for i in self.adj[v]:
            if (not self.visited[i]):
                self.DFSUtil(i)
                 
    def addEdge(self, v, w):
         
        self.adj[v].append(w)
    
         
# Driver code       
if __name__=='__main__':
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    bosses = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    people = [int(i) - 1 for i in input().split()]
    g = Graph(n, people)
    for person in range(n):
        fro = person
        to = bosses[person]
        if to == 0:
            continue
        else:
            g.addEdge(fro, to - 1)
    
    print(g.NumberOfconnectedComponents())
```

Example when my code goes wrong:

```
INPUT:
5 3
5 5 4 1 0
1 2 3

CORRECT OUTPUT: 2
MY OUTPUT: 3
```

Comment: Do you have an input for which your code produces the wrong output? Can you add this to your question  (input, expected output, wrong output)?

Comment: Yes, I added a simple example which goes wrong

Comment: @Marta Could you share the link to the problem, please?

Comment: https://po.kattis.com/problems/gratismat

Comment: It is in Swedish, but you can probably do website google translate

Comment: One simple way to avoid off-by-one errors is to keep the 1-based people numbers as strings. Never convert them to numbers, and use dictionaries instead of lists to store data about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your attempt:

- The information in `self.ppl` is not used where it should. In `NumberOfconnectedComponents` the variable `v` is an index in `self.ppl`, but apart from the `if` condition, you wrongly treat that `v` as a person (when you pass it to `DFSUtil`). You should pass `self.ppl[v]`.
- `DFSUtil` does not use `self.ppl` at all, so it assumes *all* people are present.
- `count` is counting the number of *paths* you can find from unvisited (present) people, which is not the number of disconnected components.

Not a problem, but it is also a bit strange that you store the people as 0-based indexes (by correcting with `-1`), but don't the same when storing the bosses. For those you make the correction (of `-1`) later, at the time of adding the edge.

Also not a problem, but the name `self.adj` suggests that you are storing the *children* of the node in that list, but in fact, it stores the *parent* of the node, and so `self.adj[v]` shouldn't even have to be a list -- a node has only one parent (or none). You could of course decide to use `adj` to store the children, but then your `addEdge` should swap `u` and `v`.

### Algorithm

You can indeed use recursion to walk *up* the tree (as you do), but then you should count the number of present persons for which you cannot find (upwards) a boss that is present. And something like `visited` can be used to avoid double work: a dictionary (or list) that gives the answer for already visited nodes:

### Code

```
def solve(boss_of, present_people):
    boss_is_present = [None] * len(boss_of)
    present = set(present_people)

    def find_boss(person):
        if boss_is_present[person] is None:  # undetermined
            if boss_of[person] in present:  # direct boss is present
                boss_is_present[person] = True
            elif boss_of[person] == -1:  # it is the root
                boss_is_present[person] = False
            else:
                boss_is_present[person] = find_boss(boss_of[person])
        return boss_is_present[person]
    
    count = 0
    for person in present_people:  # edge
        if not find_boss(person):
            # no higher in hierarchy is present
            count += 1
    return count

# Driver code       
if __name__=='__main__':
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    boss_of = [int(i) - 1 for i in input().split()]
    present_people = [int(i) - 1 for i in input().split()]
    print(solve(boss_of, present_people))
```

A bit more obscure, but at the end of `solve` you can remove the definition of `count` by just returning this expression:

```
    return len(present_people) - sum(int(find_boss(person)) 
                                     for person in present_people)
```

### Iterative solution

The above solution could bump into a stack overflow error if the input size is large, and the tree has a great height -- this may happen when the tree is degenerate, where every boss has about 1 subordinate.

Here is an iterative solution that maintains an explicit stack:

```
    def find_boss(person):
        stack = []
        found = False
        while person >= 0 and boss_is_present[person] is None:
            stack.append(person)
            person = boss_of[person]
            if person in present:  # boss is present
                found = True
                break
        for person in stack:
            boss_is_present[person] = found
        return found
    
    return len(present_people) - sum(int(find_boss(person)) 
                                     for person in present_people)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and code solution. I tried submitting your code in the original question (po.kattis.com/problems/gratismat) and it passes all but two test cases, where it says runtime error. I can't figure out what could be special about those cases and why they throw the error...

Comment: "runtime error" is not revealing anything. If you have anything more, I could look into it (the test case, whether it is a time out error, ...)

Comment: As maybe this is a case of stack overflow, I added an iterative version to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Observation**

There is an implicit assumption that the boss relation has no cycles: we can't have `A` and `B` being each other's boss. Moreover, because each person but one has a boss, the graph is connected. In other words, the graph is a single tree.

**Connected components**

> A person can only pay for the dinner if their boss (or indirectly any boss above them, so for eg. their bosses boss) is not present at the dinner.

This implies that your connected components approach is not going to give the right answer. Consider this org chart:

```
A (CEO)*
|
B (middle manager)
|
C (line worker)*
```

People marked with `*` are present at the dinner. Then clearly, `A` is the only one who could pay, but there are two connected components `{A}` and `{C}`.

**Hint towards solution**

One way is to traverse the tree from the top down in a depth-first or breadth-first search (order doesn't matter). As soon as you encounter a person `X` who is present, you count that person and abort that branch of the search: `X` can pay (because nobody above them was present), and nobody below `X` can pay (because `X` is, directly or indirectly, their boss).

This solution requires that you build the parent-to-children relation in memory out of the child-to-parent relation from the input, but it runs in the theoretically optimal O(n) time. (An O(m) algorithm would be nice, but reading the input is already O(n) so it doesn't bring us anything.)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think I phrased the 'connected components' wrong, because I thought of doing a depth first search (on all people) from each person that is present, and adding them to a list visited. On the next DFS's, if someone is already in that visited, I see it as one component. Otherwise, it is separate. As my graph is directed (pointing from worker to boss), my algorithm would find A from C, and therefore only return 1 in the example you gave. Could that approach be correct?

Comment: Also, if it doesn't work, could you give me a bit more hints on how to build the parent to child relation from the input given as I can't figure it out...

Comment: That part, you're basically doing already with your `adj` variable and `addEdge` method. It's just keeping a list of all direct reports for each person (as a list of lists).

Comment: The fundamental flaw in your code shows up when a boss is visited after the people below them. So if `C` is visited first, they are counted as able to pay, but then if `A` is visited later, the algorithm never goes back to say "wait, if `A` is here, `C` cannot actually pay anymore".